# Why is my UITableView not being updated?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Why does my UITableView not update? Here is how I am attempting to update it.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSArray* arrValues = [self.defaults objectForKey:@"values"];
    [self.tableScores insertRowsAtIndexPaths:arrValues withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
```

`arrValues` is now an array of NSNumbers. I am sure that it is not empty.

Comment: Please post the full code. I'm not seeing your delegate or datasource. reloadData needs these two set, and then you need to implement cellAtRowInIndexPath: to see something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `[tableScores reloadData];` in **`- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`**

### Update 1

Also, you need to define **arrValues** in your header. Each time the viewWillAppear, you are creating a new instance, but you won't be able to use it throughout the rest of your controller. This is the main reason you aren't seeing anything besides at your breakpoint.

### Update 2

According to your comment below, you have not implemented `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` which is how the cell is created. Below is an example, but you may want to search around the net for example projects because this **UITableView's 101**. There is still a lot more you need to learn when it comes to arrays and tableViews.

### Example `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"FriendCellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [arrValues objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, thanks, but the table view is still blank. I know that `arrValues` is not empty though by viewing it in the debugger after setting a breakpoint in `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: Wait, what is `cellForRowAtIndexPath`? I don't think I have that function. I produced the table view within my Nib.

Comment: That, along with the reason in my answer (see the paragraph), is why you aren;t seeing anything. **cellForRowAtIndexPath** is required to return a cell.

Comment: Thank you, how would I use `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, I meant where should I call `cellForRowAtIndexPath`? I have written a similar function in my view controller.

Comment: You don't call it manually, setting your delegate and datasource for the tableView will automagically call it when it needs to on the first load. If you change the data in your array is when you need to call **reloadData**. Like I stated before, scour the net for UITableView examples.

Comment: Don't forget to set UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate